# Android GCC Makefile, want to build shared lib and linking in static lib, without "ndk-build"

Tags: android, gcc, makefile, shared

I had some experience of android but know almost nothing of GCC Makefile. Here is what I need,
working on mac osx or linux, using android ndk toolchain, build an android shared library .so (a jni lib), linking in a prebuilt static library (already built for android). In static lib, I need logcat functions and C funcs such as sprintf. So no "ndk-build" in the process. The reason I have to do this, when linking in the static lib, a special linker is required to replace the standard arm-eabi-gcc, and the standard linker will be rolled back later.

I know that I need to set following environment variables such as:

```
ANDROID_NDK, 
PATH=$PATH:"$ANDROID_NDK/build/prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin"
MACHINE=armv7l
SYSTEM=android
ARCH=arm
CROSS_COMPILE="arm-eabi-"
ANDROID_DEV="$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr" 
HOSTCC=gcc
```

All I need is a sample Makefile, so that I can run "make" to build a .so by linking in a .a, and other necessary android and c libs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running ndk_build V=1 and recording the commands it issues in verbose mode.  Then issue comparable commands to your custom linker.

Beware the commands might change for a different ndk version.